# Firebase Realtime database is not showing data that is being written from android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem writing into Firebase real-time database. The app is running fine with no build errors. but when I look into the database nothing is changing. I am trying to write into the database. The account which is logged in in Android and Firebase is the same. I have also given the internet permission in the manifest file. I have included the JSON file in the project. I have added all the required dependencies in gradle. the gradle file

`

```
  package com.example.firebasehometry;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://fir-home-53258-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
        reference = database.getReference("student");
    add();
    }
    public void add(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "before adding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        reference.setValue("ashar khan").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error inserting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.firebasehometry'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebasehometry"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVwrR.jpg)

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
            google()  // Google's Maven repository
            mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
}
```

`

I tried all the methods that are available on internet but still realtime database is not updating. Anyone who can help me in this matter..

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something went wrong?

Comment: I have just added a Toast message in on complete listener. but the toast message is not displaying that means the value is not set.

Comment: Show the code that you're using.

Comment: `   public void add(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "before adding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        reference.setValue("ashar khan").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}`

Comment: Please add the code to your question. Have you also tried to check what is happening when the task is not successful?

Comment: I have edited the code please check. The on complete and on failure both are not displaying the toast message

Comment: How is your `reference` defined? What is the location of your database?

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: So I have edited the code again I hope you will know how the reference is defined. database is located in firebase with same account and link is attached while getting database instance

Comment: So you say that onComplete, not onFailure are even called? Are you sure you have an internet connection? Have you tried simply using `database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`? without any URL?

Comment: Database location: United States (us-central1)

Comment: Yes I have internet connection. Yes I have tried without link. Yes both function are not working

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right Firebase project in your console?

Comment: I have created database several time with different accounts I am sure I am targeting the right database

Comment: That's the reason why you most likely cannot write data to Firebase.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I am targeting the right database because when I print reference on console it shows the exact same link.

Answer (score 1):

Pass no parameters in getInstance() of FirebaseDatabase

FirebaseDatabase fd= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
make sure your project is connected with your Firebase console through the google-services.json file provided.

Comment: Still not working